# Javascript checking, if array element equals var?

Tags: javascript, arrays, triple-equals

I have an array like this:

```
var str = "This is an example sentence with the number 1";
var array = str.split(' ');

// array[8] should be 1
```

Now i want to check, if a certain variable is the same as the value of array[8]. Therefor i thought I could use:

```
var checkingnumber = 1;

if(array[8] === checkingnumber) {
    console.log("success");
    return
}
```

This doesnt seem to work in my Code. So could anyone help me, how to fix that ?

Comment: `1 !== "1"` ... `array[8] === "1"` does that help?

Comment: `===` also checks for types. the result of `str.split()` is an array of strings and not numbers (like `checkingnumber`), so your comparison fails

Comment: One question - just to play devil's advocate here - is it **always** the 9th word in the sentence?  Could it be the **last** word?  Could it be somewhere else in the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The resulting array will be strings and `===` [will compare the type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) as well.
Use `==` or [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to make sure you compare apples with apples.

```
var checkingnumber = 1;

if(parseInt(array[8]) === checkingnumber) {
    console.log("success");
    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Thats exactly what I needed and it works! :)

Comment: No worries. Feel free to mark this as the answer ;)

Comment: You mean number of apples with number of apples.